# Raspberry pi as vpn and possible leaks

Tags: networking, vpn, raspberry-pi

I have setup a raspberry as vpn in my home network in order to have my home ip even if I am not at home simply connecting to vpn first.
Being not expert in networks, my question is: there can be any leak, for example possible way my real ip could be revealed to the website or online service I connect to?
Maybe dns leaks? But in this case my ip could be revealed to the isp and not to website I connect. Am I right?

How I use VPN:  my home is in New York and raspberry sits there. When I go traveling like in Sweden I need to have my New York ip home network so I connect from my laptop with a vpn client to the vpn on raspberry

Comment: @Peregrino69 updated

Comment: Is that the whole story? I thought you're using the VPN to connect to outside world with your external address?

Comment: If you're just routing out with the RasPi and the VPN is correctly configured, the ISP you're using to connect with will only see you connecting to a single IP address elsewhere. They won't be able to descramble the actual payload traffic, nor can see where you go from the VPN egress point. Your external IP should be your own IP in the US. You can check with [DNS Leak Test](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/) whether your DNS settings are as you need them to be. The IP address you're opening the VPN from should not be known or knowable to anyone except the ISP you're using to connect.

Comment: DNS leak will only be possible if your VPN is configure in such a way where that’s possible, if it’s configured properly to prevent that from happening, it won’t be possible.  However, how you do that is documented, it also would be a different question than the one you have asked about. Of course this question has problems of its own and probably should just be turned into the question your actually asking